# Xamarin Forms: Installation of the app failed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

**Being unable to run the Xamarin project on Visual Studio.**

When I tried to run the Xamarin project on Visual Studio version 17.9.0 preview 2.0, I could not run it on Visual Studio. I am facing the below error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Installation of the app failed.
```

I tried to solve with some of the ways but got the same error mentioned above:

1. Deleting .vs, obj, and bin folders on the project and from Visual Studio, I tried to clean and rebuild the solution.
2. After deleting and checkout the project again.
3. I changed the bundle format to APK from properties and tried to rerun the project.

I have tried different solutions to fix this issue, but they didn't help. Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue?

Below is the output box log:

```
Installation of the app failed.
com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.CommandExecutionException: Installation of the app failed.
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.InternalExceptionBuilder.build(InternalExceptionBuilder.java:57)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.DdmlibDevice.installApks(DdmlibDevice.java:192)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.InstallApksCommand.lambda$execute$1(InstallApksCommand.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.AdbRunner.run(AdbRunner.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.AdbRunner.run(AdbRunner.java:61)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.InstallApksCommand.execute(InstallApksCommand.java:211)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:49)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to commit install session 393466168 with command cmd package install-commit 393466168. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.comapnyname.appname signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstallerBase.installCommit(SplitApkInstallerBase.java:99)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:85)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackages(DeviceImpl.java:1166)
    at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.device.DdmlibDevice.installApks(DdmlibDevice.java:176)
    ... 6 more
Done building project "Appname.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall but no luck.

Comment: If you create a new xamarin project by Visual Studio version 17.9.0 preview 2.0, will it work well?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I created a new xamarin project by Visual Studio version 17.9.0 preview 2.0 and it is works well.

Comment: Maybe try migrating the code to the new project? Cause it may be related to the version and configuration of xamarin forms.